# can't see myself in Skype video call

Tags: 12.04, video, webcam, skype, lenovo

I'm running 12.04 and I've installed skype via the software centre.

As with 11.10 everything works fine with 12.04 as well.

There is only one thing that does not work. I can't see myself in Skype video calls.
The video call works fine, I can see the other side the other side can see me. Buid in microphone works.

If I click on 'show myself' during the video call nothing happens.
I know that it works on Ubuntu in general as I had it working a while back on a different machine (Xubuntu 11.04).
Could that be related to the GPU? I'm now on a intel/nvidia one.

Any Ideas where I can hunt for some options or tweaking?

Comment: Try deleting and reinstalling skype.

Comment: this is a fresh install of ubuntu. but I.ve moved my config directory to this new machine.

Comment: There's a video test in Skype's interface , can you verify if that works for you?

Comment: @warl0ck Yes that works. I can see myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running on a nVidia card as well and it works for me.

Try reinstalling Skype and updating the nVidia drivers. Then when in a Skype call, click the blue video icon and then click "Start my Video".